# Check how many nodes in a B-Tree are size n

Tags: python, recursion, nodes, b-tree, treenode

Given a B-Tree, I have to look for all the nodes that are length n. However, I'm struggling to traverse with B-trees of a height greater than 1. I'm not sure how I can make my recursive call or my loop move such that I can reach the nodes at a lower level.
[image]

This is my code:

```
def nodes_with_n_items(T,n):
    L = []
    if len(T.data) == n:
        L.append(T)
    if len(T.child) == 0:
        return L
    
    for item in T.child:
        if len(item.data) == n:
            L.append(item)
        L + nodes_with_n_items(item, n)

    return L
```

This is my expected output:

```
There are 1 nodes with 1 items
[11]
There are 4 nodes with 2 items
[2, 6]
[0, 1]
[12, 13]
[15, 16]
There are 3 nodes with 3 items
[3, 4, 5]
[14, 17, 21]
[18, 19, 20]
There are 2 nodes with 4 items
[7, 8, 9, 10]
[22, 23, 24, 25]
There are 0 nodes with 5 items
```

This is my output:

```
There are 1 nodes with 1 items
[11]
There are 1 nodes with 2 items
[2, 6]
There are 1 nodes with 3 items
[14, 17, 21]
There are 0 nodes with 4 items
There are 0 nodes with 5 items
```

My class that cannot be changed:

```
def __init__(self,  max_items = 5):
        self.data = []
        self.child = []
        self.max_items = max_items
```

This is my main:

```
    print('\nQuestion 4')
    for i,T in enumerate(btree_list):
        name = 'btree_list[{}]'.format(i)
        print('\nT =',name)
        for n in range(1,6):
            #print('nodes_with_n_items(T,{}):'.format(n),end =' ')
            N = nodes_with_n_items(T,n)
            print('There are {} nodes with {} items'.format(len(N),n))
            for t in N:
                print(t.data)
```

Comment: `L + nodes_with_n_items(item, n)` does nothing. You may want to use `+=` or `.extend()`.

Comment: Your code, as presented, does not produce *any* output.

Comment: Also, doesn't it kind of defeat the purpose of recursion if you check the current node's size, then the child nodes' size, and then recursively call on the children? No need to check the children within the call, that's what recursion is for.

Comment: If you expect "There are 1 nodes with 1 items" in the output, how come your code doesn't include those words?

Comment: forgot to add my main function, just added it now

Answer (score 0):

The issues are in the `for` loop:

- `L + nodes_with_n_items(item, n)` correctly makes a recursive call, and the `+` combines `L` and that result from recursion into a new list, however that new list is going nowhere; `L` is not extended. To extend `L`, you could use `+=` instead of `+`.
- `L.append(item)` should not appear in that `for` loop, because that will be taken care of in the recursive call. The loop should only make the recursive call and add that result to `L`.

Not a problem, but you don't really need to have the `if len(T.child) == 0:` case treated separately. You can drop that `if` block. If there are no children, the loop will not make any iterations which is exactly what you want in that case.

So the corrected code becomes:

```
def nodes_with_n_items(T, n):
    L = []
    if len(T.data) == n:
        L.append(T)
    for item in T.child:
        L += nodes_with_n_items(item, n)
    return L
```

This will give the desired output.

### Alternative

You may want to consider defining a generator instead, and in the main program build the list from the generated tree nodes:

```
def nodes_with_n_items(T, n):
    if len(T.data) == n:
        yield T
    for item in T.child:
        yield from nodes_with_n_items(item, n)
```

And in your main code, replace

```
N = nodes_with_n_items(T, n)
```

with

```
N = list(nodes_with_n_items(T, n))
```